# Why can't I import conversion events from Firebase to AdWords even though the accounts are linked?

Tags: firebase, events, google-ads-api

even though I have linked the Firebase account with the AdWords account and I have owner access in Firebase and Admin in Adwords, I can see the accounts are linked, but in adwords when I go and try to import the events from Firebase as conversions in Adwords I'm not seeing any of the events....

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to import conversion to one of the Customer account under MCC in the New AdWords Interface? If yes, to import conversion you need to switch to Old AdWords Interface, Go to MCC Account, Go to 'Conversions' Menu on the left, Import conversions there, after that Share these imported conversions to your sub-account

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have linked your MCC (manager) account and not the child account. No worries you can still do this:

1. You can import the events at Manager (MCC) level - go to manager level > conversions > import firebase events.
2. Then pass on these to the the child account by going to Accounts > Under "Google Ads Conversion Account" select "This Manager"

Voila - now you will see all your events from Firebase into the child account!